# Can the phrases "as is/as it is/as it stands" be used in past tense constructions?

Tags: phrase-usage

Using a phrase that normally denotes the present state, while writing in past tense can be quite confusing. Here's an example:

> He had enough problems *as was(?) / as it is* / as it stood.*

And how about past perfect?:

> He had had enough problems *as had been(?) / as it is* / as it had stood.*

Can those phrases be used in past tense, and which form do they take? Thanks.

Comment: It is idiomatic and grammatical to write _"He had enough problems as it **was,"**_ or _"He had enough problems as it **stood,"**_ but we would almost never use the past perfect in such constructions. Just because we _can_ use the perfect in such sentences, and do so grammatically, does not mean that we _ought to!_ A useful adage in this connection is "Don't use the perfect unless you have to."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use the past perfect with that idiom in the past tense.  You want to make sure the tenses match, "He **had** enough problems as it **was**."

It's slightly awkward phrasing, though.  Remember just because you can legally make a sentence in English (or of course any language), doesn't mean it's the best way to say what you want to say.

It's hard out of context to say exactly how to say it better, but for example, "John didn't want to start a fight with Maria -- he had enough problems (as it was) and didn't need to add another."  Here "as it was" is fine, and if that sounds natural to you then roll with it.  Personally, I'd write something like "he didn't need to add to his current list of problems" ... but, the more I think about it, the more "as it was" seems fine.